# SCSS in Vue Single File component NOT compiling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-component

I've got a Vue project I'm working on where my Single File Components refuse to compile with their SCSS. There is no error so I'm not sure what to go off of.

What I've Tried:

- Reviewing Vue docs on CSS Post-processors
- Re-installed all packages and verified they exist.
- Testing the  tag lang by setting it to "sass" rather than "scss" to see if an error would happen (it did).
- Commenting out the MiniCssExtractPlugin to ensure it's not somehow getting in the way of the pipe.

Webpack.config:

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
//const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    watch: true,
    entry: {
        index: './src/scripts/index.js',
        style: './src/scss/style.scss',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
        publicPath: __dirname + '/dist/',
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async'
        },
        usedExports: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, //compiles css to file. 
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                          sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                    /*{
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                        options: {
                            debug: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },*/
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            additionalData: `@import '/src/scss/global.scss';`,
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
                myViews: path.resolve(__dirname, 'views'),
                scss: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scss'), 
                icons: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts/icons.js'),
                webfontloader: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/webfontloader/webfontloader.js"),
            }
    },
    plugins: [
        //Globals
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'webfontloader': 'webfontloader',
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: 'css/[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[name].css',
        }),
    ]
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "mgmechanical",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "M&G Mechanical Website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nps"
  },
  "author": "M&G Mechanical",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "lazysizes": "^5.2.2",
    "matchmedia-polyfill": "^0.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.10",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  }
}
```

Footer.vue:

```
<style lang="scss">
    .mg-list { 
        font-weight:Bold;
        
        .mg-list-item {
            background:Black;
        } 
    }
</style>
<template>
    <v-container tag="footer" class="accent ma-0 pa-4" fluid>
        <v-row no-gutters class='py-2'>
            <v-col cols="2" align-self="center"></v-col>
            <v-col cols="8" align-self="center">
                
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="2" align-self="center"></v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col cols="2" align-self="center"></v-col>
            <v-col cols="8" align-self="center">
                <v-row align-content="start" justify="center">
                    <ul class='mg-list'>
                        <li class='mg-list-item' v-for='(area, index) in areas' :key='index' v-html='area'></li>
                    </ul>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="2" align-self="center"></v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'footer',
        data: function() {
            return {
                areas: [],
            }    
        },
        methods: {
        },
        computed: {
        },
        mounted: function() {

        }
    }
</script>
```